# Django2-Signal, al crear/modificar usuario incluirlo a Group segun un atributo

Tags: django, django-models, permisos, users-roles, signals

Modelo usuario personalizado, usando Django 2.2. Quise pasar la funcion post_save del modelo a un Signal para que funcione tambien desde el Admin.
En la funcion post_save cuando modificaba un usuario o lo creaba, se asignaba a un grupo especifico, en funcion de ciertos atributos, sin problemas.
Ahora en signal, no queda guardado el nuevo usuario, sin embargo cuando asocio el grupo desde el admin, noto que su auto_id se ha incrementado en cada oportunidad que quise agregarlo por codigo.
Este es mi codigo dentro de usuario.models.py:

```
def asignar_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   if instance.is_docente:
      grupo = Group.objects.get(name=‘DOCENTE’)
   elif instance.is_alumno:
      grupo = Group.objects.get(name=‘ALUMNO’)
   else:
      grupo = Group.objects.get(name=‘USER’)

instance.groups.add(grupo)

post_save.connect(asignar_group, sender=Usuario)
```

Están las importaciones de:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
```

Mi modelo Usuario hereda de AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

Seguro es algo trivial, pues no encontré muchos programadores planteando este problema en la web.

En el intento 315 :(, logré resolverlo parcialmente. Usando

```
instance.groups.set([grupo.id])
```

es decir agregando el id de la instancia lo hace PERO SOLO DESDE EL CRUD de mi app, no desde el ADMIN.

Otro cambio que hice fue usar .set() agregando en la tupla solo el grupo nuevo, porque conservaba el que ya tenia, que a efectos de las reglas del negocio a mi no me servía.

Si alguien puede decirme ¿el porque? de esto o sugerirme documentacion en español al respecto Agradeceré. Es decir porque no actualiza desde el ADMIN, y porque no lo hacia antes de ponerle el .id.

Publique mi solucion de compromiso por si otro está con el mismo problema porque en verdad busque varios dias en la web. Gracias =mente